# assembly data addressing how does little endian work?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, endianness

```
.data
x dw 7A6H, 30B0H
y db 20H
z dw 1, 2, 3
.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
lea si, y
mov bl, [si+2]
```

The value of the register bl is 0, why is that? Shouldn't it be 2 from the z dw array?

Comment: If you want the value 2 from the z array use might use `lea si, z; mov bx, [si+2]`. That will start with z, index by 1 to get to the second element (*2 or scaled by 2, due to size of elements being 16-bits), then fetch the whole 16-bit value into bx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should be zero. Data is laid out like

```
x           y  z
A6 07 B0 30 20 01 00 02 00 03 00
```

So [y+2] is 0.

In high level languages we have indexing operations that take the sizes into account. Assembly just doesn't do that.